# How can I remove a folder located in the same folder of my setup after installation in Wix?

Tags: wix

I am trying to make a setup file for an application with Wix. After the installation of the program the setup should remove a folder located in its same folder. I don't know how to do it. All I know is that I have to use the RemoveFolder element, that must be placed inside a Component element. So far I have written this but it doesn't work.

```
<Component Directory="CURRENTDIR" Id="cd1">
      <RemoveFolder Id="rf1" On="install" Directory="NameOfFolderToRemove"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: Maybe with custom actions that's possible

Comment: Is that folder being deployed by a different deployer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at util:RemoveFolderEx

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html

You will need to reference WixUtilExtension in your project and include

> xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"

in your Wix tag like below:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

<RemoveFolder> will only remove empty folders so if there are files in the folder the remove folder action won't work.